# Prove that the sequence of L-Lipschitz functions converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

$f_n(x): [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ are a sequence of functions that all are $L$-Lipschitz:
means -

$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le L|x-y|$ , ($L$ is for all the functions)
and assume $f_n \to f$ in a pointwise convergence.

By now I know that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz as well. 
I need to prove that $f_n \to f$  in a **uniform convergence**.
what I tried to do is using the Triangle inequality :

$$ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\le|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(x)|\le 2L|x-y|+ |fn(y)-f(y)|$$

and I can't continue from here.. because from pointwise convergence all I can know is that for every $x$ there's a diffferent $n_1$ such that for every $n>n_1$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ is less than $\epsilon$, but I need one $n_1$ that is suitable for all the $x$'s in order to prove uniform convergence..

Please help me :(

Comment: You want to prove that it converges to a Lipschitz function.

Comment: I need to prove uniform convergence, how will it help me?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Ascoli-Arzela theorem?

Comment: never heard of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$: pick points $x_1,\dots,x_m \in [a,b]$ which are distance $\epsilon/(3L)$ from each other.

For each $1 \le i \le m$, find a number $N_i$ so that for all $n \ge N_i$ we have $|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)| \le \epsilon/3$.  Let $N = \max_{1 \le i \le m} N_i$.

Now given any $x \in [a,b]$, pick $1 \le i \le m$ such that $|x-x_i| < \epsilon/(2L)$.  Go from there to show that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ if $n \ge N$.

Comment: I still don't get how to do it.. starting with the N that I need to find

Comment: For each $1 \le i \le m$, you find a number $N_i$ so that for all $n \ge N_i$ we have $|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)| \le \epsilon/3$.  Now let $N = \max_{1 \le i \le m} N_i$.